# Removing \u2018 and \u2019 character

Tags: python, html, string

I am using Beautiful Soup to parse webpages and printing the name of the webpages visited on the terminal. However, often the name of the webpage has single left (`\u2018`) and right (`\u2019`) character which Python can't print as it gives a charmap encoding error.

Is there any way to remove these characters?

Comment: please add some of your code and your Output and expected output. it will be good to Draw better solutions

Comment: Note:
U+2018 = Left Single Quotation Mark, 

U+2019 = Right Single Quotation Mark

Comment: sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer, encoding="UTF-8")

is helpful to avoid encoding error in the first place.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

These codes are Unicode for the single left and right quote characters. You can replace them with their ASCII equivalent which Python shouldn't have any problem printing on your system:

```
>>> print u"\u2018Hi\u2019"
‘Hi’
>>> print u"\u2018Hi\u2019".replace(u"\u2018", "'").replace(u"\u2019", "'")
'Hi'
```

Alternatively with regex:

```
import re
s = u"\u2018Hi\u2019"
>>> print re.sub(u"(\u2018|\u2019)", "'", s)
'Hi'
```

However Python shouldn't have any problem printing the Unicode version of these as well. It's possible that you are using `str()` somewhere which will try to convert your unicode to ascii and throw your exception.

Answer (score 0):

Since single characters (`\u2018` and `\u2019`) need to be replaced, `str.translate()` could be used as well.

```py
s = "\u2018Hi\u2019"
s_new = s.translate(str.maketrans({'\u2018': "'", '\u2019': "'"}))

# or even use the unicode characters themselves
s_new = s.translate(str.maketrans({'‘': "'", '’': "'"}))
print(s_new)   # 'Hi'
```

Or specify the encoding in the first place when parsing.

```py
# if parsing an html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, from_encoding='utf-8')

# if reading a file
with open("text.txt", encoding='utf-8') as f:
     f.read()
```