# Removing non latin characters from a string in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm passing a string to `PIL`'s `multiline_text()` which, for some reason, doesn't support utf-8 but only Latin characters.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

input_string = "‘Hi’"

img_width = 500
img_height = 500
img = Image.new('RGB', (img_width, img_height), (255, 255, 255))
img_D = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
img_D.multiline_text((0, 0), input_string)    # <- bug here
img.save("test_img.jpeg", 'jpeg', optimize=True, quality = 200)
```

I get this error message: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2018' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)`

So I need to get rid of all non-Latin characters. How can I do that?

Note: I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24358544/4348534), namely `input_string = regex.sub(ur'[^\p{Latin}]', u'', t1)` but I'm pretty sure it's for Python2, I get the following error: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. If I remove either the `u` or the `r` or both, I get `error: bad escape \p`.

Answer (score 0):

Found a partial way:

```
input_string = "‘Hi’"

input_string = input_string.encode("latin", "ignore") 
# you can also try "replace" but in the case of ‘ and ’ it doesn't work as it outputs b'?Hi?'

print(input_string)
# b'Hi' is a bytes object, to turn it back into a string, do:

input_string = input_string.decode("utf-8", "ignore") 
# same thing, you can also try "replace", but it might lose you some characters

print(input_string)
# Hi
```

However, on longer strings, it also strips accented characters (`éèàù`) so it's not perfect...

Comment: This approach is okay. Alternatively, if you use a font with support for unicode characters, you will not need to strip these characters from a unicode string.

Comment: It's actually not, I lose accented characters. By "if I use a font", you mean in PIL? Can you point me to a (monospaced) font which supports unicode characters?

Comment: Hi again, based on this comment you might want to edit your question to indicate that you are asking about how to render non-latin characters. I have provided an answer below to help you work through loading and rendering with a font that supports unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

Since your comment clarified your question is about rendering unicode characters rather than stripping unicode characters, I will provide an example of loading and drawing with a font that supports unicode characters.

For this example I used [Roboto Mono Bold](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Mono) which you can download from Google Fonts.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

haiku = '''bruits de neige et d’encre
frôlement d’âmes et d’ailes
deux papillons s’aiment'''

font = ImageFont.truetype('RobotoMono-Bold.ttf', 18)
haiku_dimensions = font.getsize_multiline(haiku)

padding = 4
with Image.new('RGB', tuple(d + (4 * padding) for d in haiku_dimensions), color=(180, 180, 180)) as image:
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    draw.multiline_text((padding, padding), haiku, font=font, fill=(20,20,20))
    image.save('output.png')
```

The output looks like this:

[image: A haiku with French characters]